# Overriding default parameter when building one Jenkins pipeline from another

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

Goal: override a Jenkins Boolean parameter default value (true) with false when I build from another Jenkins script

I've check the suggested possible answers from other StackOverflow items; nothing seems to match. They did, however, show me how to use parameters when calling one Jenkins script from another. (Thanks!)

I can pass a value of true to a non-default parameter to change its value from false to true. But when I try to pass a value of false to a parameter where I have checked the "Default Value" box in the Configure view, the value stays true.

Jenkins is running on Windows 10

```
build job: 'other_build', parameters[booleanParam(name: 'param_no_default_value', value: true) ]

build job: 'other_build', parameters[booleanParam (name: 'param_default_value', value: false) ]
```

Overriding the parameter that doesn't have a default value works. Trying to override the parameter that does have a default value doesn't work. So does checking the value in the configuration file trump setting it from the other job?

== Added May 9, in response to @hakamairi's request for configuration (note: this is in Jenkins web interface): ==

```
In General area:
[checked] This project is parameterized
Boolean Parameter
Name: param_no_default_value
Default Value: [unchecked]

Boolean Paremeter
Name: param_default_value
Default Value: [checked]
```

In "Build with parameters," I do not check any boxes

Is there anything else that would help you?

Comment: I did a quick practice, specified parameter value can overwrite the default value on my jenkins.  Please double check you give correct parameter name, and check it's a bug of  [build step plugin | https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Build+Step+Plugin] on your version.

Comment: Show us your job configuration please.

Comment: @TheBick, did you get any solution for this? I amalso facing the same issue. The default value is not getting overrideen in the called pipeline. The called pipeline is getting executed with the default values set in it.

build job: abcd', parameters:[booleanParam(name: 'xyz', value:'true')], wait: false
is not replacing the default value of false in the pipeline abcd